# What language (or languages) are the next 'big thing'?

Tags: internationalization

Having (mostly) learned how to navigate Python programming in GIS, I've gotten to thinking about where GIS programming is going from here.  I know VB used to be the go-to language for ArcGIS, but that has been supplanted by Python.  I love Python's utility, ease of use, and support in a variety of spatial and non-spatial programs,  but I know these are no guarantee of it sticking around.

I'm curious about which languages I should keep an eye on and consider dabbling in to be ahead of the curve.  I've seen a few options out there.  For example [Geoscript](http://geoscript.org/) has libraries for Scala and Groovy in addition to js and Python.

What up-and-coming programming languages are trending towards increased use, increasing geospatial functionality, and cross-application scripting?

Comment: I suggest that you [future-proof](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Future_proof) your question by changing it a bit.  [Many believe questions about the future are not answerable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20668/new-close-reason-question-asks-to-predict-the-future).

Comment: community wiki as can change direction within a few months

Comment: Programming languages used in GIS can also be platform dependent (.NET for ArcObjects).

Comment: It's an interesting question but as currently phrased it is guaranteed to get awful answers. Please consider how to motivate *objective,* well-reasoned answers.  If that seems impossible, then this question truly does not belong here and ought to be carried out in chat.

Comment: Hmmm... I forget that I can be a bit over-optimistic about how likely people are to opinionated.  I'll try to restructure it, but I think you're right that it may be a better candidate for chat.

Comment: Looks good now, "trending" is [certainly quantifiable](http://www.google.com/trends/explore?q=arcpy#q=arcpy&cmpt=q).

Comment: d3js can better arcpy http://www.google.com/trends/explore?q=d3js%2C%20arcpy&cmpt=q#q=d3js%2C%20arcpy&cmpt=q

Comment: @Mapperz Some of us jumped on Silverlight in 2008 after seeing a [similar trend](http://www.google.com/trends/explore?q=d3js%2C%20arcpy&cmpt=q#q=silverlight&cmpt=q).

Comment: As Kirk notes and Mapperz extends the example of, trends can be a quantifiable. On that basis I'll reopen.

Comment: More interesting, and perhaps more revealing, than "what is next language?" might be "what drives a language change?", though that's even murkier and harder to get a definitive answer for... :)

Comment: I think you could have a safe bet on Python sticking around. The main point is you shouldn't just know one thing.

Answer (score 5):

Not that it's going to be exactly the *next big thing* but as now there is a *trend* to do apps *on the cloud* **`javascript`** is getting a lot of interest as is the *de facto* standard for browser scripting.

Also there are many pages trying to measure the popularity of programing languages (some examples):

- [Programming Language Popularity Chart](http://langpop.corger.nl/)
- [The Transparent Language Popularity Index](http://lang-index.sourceforge.net/)
- [PYPL PopularitY of Programming Language index](https://sites.google.com/site/pydatalog/pypl/PyPL-PopularitY-of-Programming-Language)
- [The RedMonk Programming Language Rankings: January 2013](http://redmonk.com/sogrady/2013/02/28/language-rankings-1-13/)
- [Trendy Skills](http://trendyskills.com/)
- [Programming Language Popularity](http://www.langpop.com/)

Those are **not** *GIS specific* but most of those *top* programming languages had their GIS libraries.

On the other hand if you check here the [popular tag list](https://gis.stackexchange.com/tags?tab=popular) you can see that after [python](/questions/tagged/python) is [openlayers](/questions/tagged/openlayers) (that means `javascript`) and then [postgis](/questions/tagged/postgis) (so `SQL` would be interesting also).

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it all depends on your field. Also there isn't a one 'super language' thats its good for everything.

And don't confuse algorithm designing with the linguistic interpretation.

The geospatial extension of python flourish so much because (imo) it the timing and the conditions were right, but as everything eventually will give its way to something newer and better (or with easier syntax -if possible).

So if you want to focus on something, focus on problem solving and functional programming. The rest is about choosing the right tools for the job.